# iPad SplitView detailView default load

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad split-view app. The detailview is a webview. In which method, can I get a default page loaded when the app launch before the user clicks on an item in the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN detailviewcotroller.h , create outlet as follows,

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *WEBVIEW;
```

connect outlet in xib by drag n droping uiwebview control.

In your detailviewcontroller.m's viewdidload method u can write as follows-

```
    NSString *str=@"yr default webpage link here";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [WEBVIEW loadRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a good advice, by creating Outlets, when you synthesize do:

@synthesize webView = _webView;

and use :

[_webView loadRequest:req];

for loading your request.